# Can't call a service reference?

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have a service which i have connected too but can't call it from my controller.

I right clicked on my project and then clicked add service reference, i pasted in my URL and clicked go. It found the reference and when i clicked on it a whole list of action popped up on the right. I gave the service a name called Stormzo.

Following the support document i should be able to Instantiate the service as follows

```
Stormzo.RegistryServiceClient stormzoService = new Stormzo.RegistryServiceClient();
```

How ever the Stormzo is underlined in red?

When i hover over it, it says:

> could not find namespace or missing assembly reference.

Am i missing a using statement? Or how can i make the service visible to the code controller?

Comment: actually best way is interface to assign the instance of the service class.ServiceReference1.IService1 asda = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click your service reference and go to:

Configure service reference -> Advanced -> Untick the Reuse types in referenced assemblies

Comment: @Yuval Can you please expalin?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I was thinking where did you know that this was the problem. It worked for me the solution seemed to come from nowhere :).

Comment: @Corovei The same thing happened to me while trying to implement a service. That's how I knew what the problem was :)